# Transition not working on transform property when toggling active class

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, modal-dialog

I have a modal that is supposed to scale in and out depending on whether it has a class of 'active'. However, whenever I toggle the class on/off it either fully scales out or scales in without any transition.

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(.75);
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    border: 10px double #fff8fb;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    background-color: #fcdce9;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 80%;
    z-index: 10;
}

.modal.active {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.modal-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: .25rem .5rem;
}

.modal-header .title {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-header .close-modal {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.post-it {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16;
}

.modal-footer {
    padding: .5rem 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.create-button {
    border: 3px solid #fff8fb;
    border-radius: 1em;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2.5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 500ms ease-in-out;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    pointer-events: none;
}

#overlay.active {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

I am unsure whether the issue is with the classes or not. When I tried to test the animation on hover, it works.
I also tried specifying what property to transition, but it still won't work. I even tried to transition all.

Comment: you need to specify what property you want to transition `transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;`

Comment: I tried specifying what property to transition, but it still won't work. I even tried to transition all.

Comment: Are you sure there's no override from another CSS chunk that cancels `transform`? Your CSS seems fine

Comment: Just tested your CSS, it does indeed work fine, I'd suggest to open the CSS inspector and look for other classes that interfere with your `transform` definitions

Comment: Please provide enough code so we can see the problem for ourselves, as others have said, your code so far as we can see it looks OK. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Note that if you are using Safari there's some tweaks you might need like `-webkit-transition`

Comment: Give me one moment while I edit my question with more code.

Comment: I apologize if I'm not making myself clear. It's my first time participating on stack overflow. Thank you for your patience

Comment: You still need to give us some proper code to reproduce the problem. _"Give me one moment while I edit my question with more code."_ - you said that a quarter of an hour ago, yet the last edit of your question is 40 minutes old.

Comment: Sorry! I was in the middle of class. I just updated it containing all relevant CSS. If needed I can also edit in my HTML in case that would help with clarity. Thank you!